# Fancybox links to specific tabs in an iframe with tabify, doesnt work

Tags: jquery, iframe, tabs, fancybox

Not sure if the title helps much but basically I have a lightbox that links to an iframe that runs Fanybox, which loads an iframe with a jquery 'tabify' plugin.

Here is a live link:

http://intp.co/periodic-table/table.html

The link for the fancybox is like this:

```
<a href="elements.html#Li" class="element fancybox.iframe"><img src="elements/Li.png" alt="Lithium"></a>
```

it loads the box, but doesn't select the content. this is what I'm looking to happen:

http://intp.co/periodic-table/elements.html#Zr-tab

Unfortunately the iframe link for fancybox doesn't load it up like this.

Comment: I don't see how this is a fancybox issue. If you open the link in a new tab (outside fancybox), it doesn't work either because the elements are hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given link proper. '-tab' is added in href.

```
 <a href="elements.html#Li-tab" class="element fancybox.iframe"><img src="elements/Li.png" alt="Lithium"></a>
```

Comment: Ahh, what an oversight on my part. This was properly doing my head in. Thanks for helping me figure that out.. . I definitely should have spotted thi, how embarrassing